# (React Error) BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, buffer

I am currently working on a simple project in which I am practicing the user authentication process and I was able to set the registration and login process correctly, but when I reached the stage of verifying whether the user is logged in or not via the token, I get this error
[image]

this is the code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Dashboard() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if(token) {
      const user = jwt.decode(token)
      if(!user) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        <Navigate to="/login" />
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: When I delete the inside of the useEffect the error still showing, it's only disappear when I delete the jwt import